# Sinus (SIN) calculation PHP and MySQL/Doctrine differs

Tags: php, math, doctrine

I am using a script for calculating distance between coordinates.
However, the total distance should be 8 KM, which is right in PHP, and is 3000+ in SQL/Doctrine.

When I output one single calculation in both PHP and SQL/Doctrine; this is the result:

PHP: SIN(53.18882060000001 * 0.0174532925199433) = **0.8006144758170634**

SQL: SIN(53.18882060000001 * 0.0174532925199433) = **0.8006144758170636**

As you can see; the difference is **0.0000000000000002**.

Looks small, but I am using this; the different is a way off:

PHP:

(ACOS(SIN(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) * SIN(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) + COS(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) * COS(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) * COS(5.556485699999939*0.0174532925199433 - 5.43966*0.0174532925199433)) * 6371)

**8.204067263544099** KM

SQL/Doctrine:

(ACOS(SIN(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) * SIN(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) + COS(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) * COS(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) * COS(5.556485699999939*0.0174532925199433 - 5.43966*0.0174532925199433)) * 6371)

**3296.761195521706** KM

It doesn't matter if I set the precision of PHP to 16 (defaults to 14), the total distance stays the same.

How can I fix this? I am using this in a Symfony 3 project with Doctrine extensions to support SIN, COS and ACOS.

---

More calculations:

**PHP:**

sin1: sin(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) = **0.8006144758170634**

sin2: sin(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) = **0.8003711646618459**

cos1: cos(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) = **0.5991798236858188**

cos2: cos(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) = **0.5995047946245639**

cos3: cos(5.556485699999939*0.0174532925199433 - 5.43966*0.0174532925199433) = **0.9999979212542568**

**SQL:**

sin1: sin(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) = **0.8006144758170636**

sin2: sin(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) = **0.800371164661846**

cos1: cos(53.18882060000001*0.0174532925199433) = **0.3809279376844091**

cos2: cos(53.1655606*0.0174532925199433) = **0.3820183930527858**

cos3: cos(5.556485699999939*0.0174532925199433 - 5.43966*0.0174532925199433) = **1.568757332266098**

---

This is the Doctrine query I try to run using Symfony:

```
$lat = 53.18882060000001;
$lng = 5.556485699999939;
$tlat = 53.1655606;
$tlng = 5.43966;

$sql = "SELECT  L,
                    L.latitude AS lat,
                    L.longitude AS lng,

                    SIN(1) AS tmp,
                    SIN($lat*$rad) AS sin1,
                    SIN($tlat*$rad) AS sin2,
                    COS($lat*$rad) AS cos1,
                    COS($tlat*$rad) AS cos2,
                    COS($lng*$rad - $tlng*$rad) AS cos3,
                    (SIN($lat*$rad) * SIN($tlat*$rad) + COS($lat*$rad) * COS($tlat*$rad)) AS test,
                    (sin($lat*$rad) * sin($tlat*$rad) + cos($lat*$rad) * cos($tlat*$rad) * COS($lng*$rad - $tlng*$rad)) AS test1,
                    ACOS(SIN($lat*$rad) * SIN($tlat*$rad) + COS($lat*$rad) * COS($tlat*$rad) * COS($lng*$rad - $tlng*$rad)) AS test2,
                    ACOS(0.5174636941643757) AS test3,

                    (ACOS(SIN($lat*$rad) * SIN($tlat*$rad) + COS($lat*$rad) * COS($tlat*$rad) * COS($lng*$rad - $tlng*$rad)) * 6371) as dist
            FROM    AppBundle:Location AS L
            ";
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($sql)->getResult();
```

Comment: You should post your code, because for example your `cos1` value in sql is way off and I cannot reproduce that in sql.

Comment: You don't say what DBMS you're using, but MySQL and Postgres both output 0.5991798236858185 for your `cos1` example for me - which is identical to PHP when precision is set to 16

Comment: Even if they always generate the same solution, you still shouldn't assume that they will be exactly the same. You should not compare evaluated floating points directly even if they are supposedly the same function (e.g. `sin($x)` vs `cos(M_PI_2 - $x)`), much less evaluation from different implementations.

Comment: @jeroen This is in Doctine. Here I do exactly this:

SIN($lat*$rad) AS sin1,
SIN($tlat*$rad) AS sin2,
COS($lat*$rad) AS cos1,
COS($tlat*$rad) AS cos2,
COS($lng*$rad - $tlng*$rad) AS cos3,

(Using PHP variables to inject the values to only test the SIN() function result.)

Comment: Added actual code.

Comment: If I run `cos1` directly in CLI mysql, I get `0.5991798236858186`. I don't know why Doctrine makes it so hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Seemed that the ACOS/COS/SIN extensions I found for Doctrine were not really that great.

I know used these; and its all fixed now:

https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Cos.php

https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Sin.php

https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Acos.php

https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Round.php